# JavaScript: TypeError: work.calls is not iterable in function decorator (beginner question)

Tags: javascript, decorator, typeerror

I was trying to pass a function `work` into a decorator where it will save function calls in an array `work.calls`.

The function:

```
work(a, b) {
  console.log(a + b);
}
```

The decorator:

```
function decorator(func) {
  func.calls = [];
  return function(...args) {
    func.calls.push(args);
    return func.call(this, ...args);
  }
}
```

Decorate function `work`:

```
work = decorator(work);
```

Calling new function:

```
work(1, 2); // 3
work(4, 5); // 9

for (let args of work.calls) {
  console.log( 'call:' + args.join() ); // TypeError: work.calls is not iterable
}
```

`work.calls` is an array so why is it not iterable?

For reference, there's another version of decorator written by someone else that actually works:

```
function decorator(func) {

  function wrapper(...args) {
    wrapper.calls.push(args);
    return func.apply(this, arguments);
  }

  wrapper.calls = [];

  return wrapper;
}

work(1, 2); // 3
work(4, 5); // 9

for (let args of work.calls) {
  alert( 'call:' + args.join() ); // "call:1,2", "call:4,5"
}
```

What does `wrapper` do here and why this way works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2 functions do not work the same. Your decorator defines the `calls` property on the passed function. The other decorator function sets the property on the nested and returned (`wrapper`) function. You get that error as `work.calls` is `undefined`. The decorated `work` refers to the anonymous function: `return function(...args)` which doesn't have `calls` property.

If you change `work = decorator(work);` to `let work2 = decorator(work);` then you will see that `calls` is set on the original `work` function and not on `work2`.

Your code works the same if you define the `calls` property on the returned function of the closure.

```
function decorator(func) {
  function __(a, b) {
    __.calls.push([a, b])
    return func(a, b)
  }
  __.calls = []
  return __;
}
```